# How to manipulate xml object directly in nodejs without converting to json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xml

I am using Nodejs and javascript framework. I have an xml object as below. I would like to delete a property from it.

```
<soapenv:Envelope><xmlns:soapenv>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/?........
....
....
.....
<memberId>123</memberId>
..
</soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

I want to delete property memberId from the above xml.
I tried parsing it to json and deleting the property but parsing back xml again changes the xml object completely.

for example: I have empty xmls tags as

```
<ProductNumber xmlns="">1111</ProductNumber>
```

converting xml to json changes the above xml to

```
"ProductNumber":{"_":"1111","xmlns":""}
```

and converting this json to xml gives me the below xml:

```
<ProductNumber><_>1111</_><xmlns/></ProductNumber>
```

Thats the reason I want to edit xml object directly instead of parsing it to json and back. Can anyone help how can I delete a property from xml object directly in nodejs.